# Apply a list of Python functions in order elegantly

Tags: python, functional-programming, function-composition

I have an input value `val` and a list of functions to be applied in the order:

```
funcs = [f1, f2, f3, ..., fn]
```

How to apply elegantly and not writing

```
fn( ... (f3(f2(f1(val))) ... )
```

and also not using for loop:

```
tmp = val
for f in funcs:
    tmp = f(tmp)
```

Thanks Martijn for the awesome answer. There's some reading I found: https://mathieularose.com/function-composition-in-python/ .

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use the [`reduce()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
# forward-compatible import
from functools import reduce

result = reduce(lambda res, f: f(res), funcs, val)
```

`reduce()` applies the first argument, a callable, to each element taken from the second argument, plus the accumulated result so far (as `(result, element)`). The third argument is a starting value (the first element from `funcs` would be used otherwise).

In Python 3, the built-in function was moved to the [`functools.reduce()` location](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce); for forward compatibility that same reference is available in Python 2.6 and up.

Other languages may call this [folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#Folds_in_various_languages).

If you need *intermediate* results for each function too, use [`itertools.accumulate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) (only from Python 3.3 onwards for a version that takes a function argument):

```
from itertools import accumulate, chain
running_results = accumulate(chain([val], funcs), lambda res, f: f(res))
```

Comment: Perfect answer! I love OCaml's `List.fold_left` and in Python we have `functools.reduce()` :)

Comment: @Viet: see the [Wikipedia list of *fold* in various programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#Folds_in_various_languages).

Answer (score 9):

MartijnPieters answer is excellent. The only thing I would add is that this is called [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition)

Giving names to these generics means you can use them whenever the need arises

```
from functools import reduce

def id(x):
  return x

def comp(f,g):
  return lambda x: f(g(x))

def compose(*fs):
  return reduce(comp, fs, id)

# usage
# compose(f1, f2, f3, ..., fn) (val)

print(compose (lambda x: x + 1, lambda x: x * 3, lambda x: x - 1) (10))
# = ((10 - 1) * 3) + 1
# = 28
```

Sometimes you want it to look nicer though -

```
def seq (x): return lambda k: seq (k (x))

def fn1 (x): return x - 1
def fn2 (x): return x * 3
def fn3 (x): return x + 1

seq (10) (fn1) (fn2) (fn3) (print) # 28
         # 10    9    27    28
```

And sometimes you want more flexibility -

```
from operator import add, mul, sub

def seq (x):
  return lambda k, *v: seq (k (x, *v))

seq (10) (sub, 1) (mul, 3) (add, 1) (print) # 28
          # 10       9        27       28

seq (1) (add, 2) (add, 3) (add, 4) (add, 5) (print) # 15
        # 1        3        6        10       15
```