# Create a new function from a list of functions

Tags: python

Consider a few simple functions:

```py
add2 = lambda x: x+2
add3 = lambda x: x+3
add4 = lambda x: x+4
```

And having them stored in a list:

```py
funcs = [add2, add3, add4]
```

Is there a way, how to create a new function, which applies all the given ones?

---

Not working solution:

```py
f = funcs[0]
for g in funcs[1:]:
    f = lambda x: g(f(x))
```

This does not work, since after trying to call the create function `f(0)`, I get `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`, which I don't completely understand.

---

The solution for the question [Apply a list of Python functions in order elegantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39123375/apply-a-list-of-python-functions-in-order-elegantly?noredirect=1&lq=1) does not work for my problem.

I don't want to get to the result (yet), I want to construct a new function

```py
from functools import reduce

result = reduce(lambda res, f: f(res), funcs, val)
```

However, it should work with a combination of partial.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution with `functools`:

```py
import functools
f = functools.partial(functools.reduce, lambda res, f: f(res), funcs)
```

---

Working solution (without lambdas):

```py
def _inner(x): 
     for f in funcs: 
         x = f(x) 
     return x
```

Calling `_inner(0)` returns correctly `9`.