# Is it possible to stack multiple transformations/functions in PyTorch into a single function?

Tags: python, function, deep-learning, pytorch, vectorization

Is it possible to stack multiple transformations/functions in PyTorch into a single function? I'm ideally looking for something like this (possibly with more care taken over tensor shapes):

```py
import torch

f_stack = torch.stack([lambda x: x+1, lambda x: x*2, lambda x: x*x])

f_stack(torch.tensor([0, 0, 0]))
# >>> torch.Tensor([1, 0, 0])

f_stack(torch.tensor([3, 3, 3]))
# >>> torch.Tensor([4, 6, 9])

f_stack(torch.tensor([3, 0, 0]))
# >>> torch.Tensor([4, 0, 0])
```

Comment: You can also accomplish this with `reduce` for arbitrary sequential python functions, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39123375/apply-a-list-of-python-functions-in-order-elegantly

Comment: Hi @DerekG , thanks for your comment. I was a bit unclear in the question, what I'm looking for is a bit different to `reduce`, I'm looking to stack different functions into a single vectorised function that is applied element-wise to each element in the input. I've updated the example in the question to hopefully be a bit clearer

Answer (score 0):

One way you may try is [pipelined execution](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/pipeline.html#pipelined-execution), though I haven't tried it myself.

It does seem you are going out of your way to force torch to behave like it wasn't designed to behave, and here are some likely design considerations:

In general, running code on GPU utilizes an [SPMD model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_program,_multiple_data). This means, that a single function is meant to run in parallel on many independent data items.

I can only assume your data is many (say `n`) vectors `[a, b, c]` and functions `[fa, fb, fc]`, and you want to parallelize on `n` such `[a, b, c]`'s, with some magic

```
torch.vectorize(inputs_nx3, functions_1x3)  # doesn't exist.
```

The same results can be achieved by transposing the representations:

```
as_nx1 = # collect your a's to a vector
bs_nx1 = # collect your b's to a vector
cs_nx1 = # collect your c's to a vector

a_result = fa(as_nx1) # heavy lifting happens here in parallel
b_result = fb(bs_nx1) # heavy lifting happens here in parallel
c_result = fc(cs_nx1) # heavy lifting happens here in parallel

collected_result = torch.stack([a_result, b_result, c_result])
```

This assumes that the heavy part is the calculation of the functions `fa`, `fb`, `fc`. If it isn't (such as not enough data [small `n`] or other reasons), you can resort to just using cpu, and then stick with numpy, though there too, it is meant to be used like just stated.

In any case, vectorization is done *on the data*, meaning, vectors should represent multiple instances *of the same thing*, then single functions can operate on all of them.

<s>Yes, see [pytorch's transform.compose](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.transforms.Compose.html)</s>

for example

```
import transforms as T

   transform = T.Compose(
        [
            T.CropToClass(crop_to_class=crop_to_class),
            T.RemoveClasses(remove_classes=remove_classes),
            T.To_3ch_GRAY(to_3ch_gray),
            T.Illumination_correction(do_correction),
            T.Crop(crop_size, crop_factor, crop_warp_percent=crop_warp_percent),
            T.CompressImageQuality(prob=compress_prob, jpeg_quality=jpeg_quality),
            T.Warp(warp_percent=warp_percent),
            T.Resize(min_size, max_size),
            T.RandomHorizontalFlip(hflip_prob),
            T.RandomVerticalFlip(vflip_prob),
            T.RandomRotate90(rotate90_prob),
            T.RandomHistogramEqualization(random_equalize_prob),
            T.ToTensor(),
            T.Normalize(mean=cfg.INPUT.PIXEL_MEAN, std=cfg.INPUT.PIXEL_STD, to_bgr255=cfg.INPUT.TO_BGR255),
        ]
    )
```

You can also define custom transforms, [like so](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html#transforms)

Comment: Hi @Gulzar, thanks for your answer. I was a bit unclear in the question, what I'm looking for is a bit different to `compose`, I'm looking to stack different functions into a single vectorised function that is applied element-wise to each element in the input. I've updated the example in the question to hopefully be a bit clearer

Comment: @JakeLevi this is no different. You should compose your custom functions. Build them like I show in the second link (or use GPT to build them for you)

Comment: Is this not applying the same functions sequentially to all elements in the tensor? That's not what I want. Say I have a tensor x = [x1, x2, x3] and functions [f1, f2, f3] that I want to stack into a single vectorised function f, I think using compose would do something like f1(f2(f3([x1, x2, x3]))), what I want is to stack the individual functions into a single vectorised function that does f(x) = [f1(x1), f2(x2), f3(x3)] (I think this should be clear from the updated example I gave in the question)

Comment: @JakeLevi I see now. Please see edit.